# Conditionally passing ownership for members

Tags: c++, move-semantics, ownership-semantics

Assume the following sketch:

```cpp
struct C {
    (either T or T&) m_t;
    C(T& t):
        (instantiate m_t as T& m_t(t))
    {}
    C(T&& t):
        (instantiate m_t as T(t))
    {}
};
```

such that a `C` either has or has not ownership of `t`, depending on how the `C` was constructed. Is that possible, possibly without resorting to `shared_ptr` and thus having to move everything to heap? I'm trying around with `std::variant`, but without success so far.

Comment: Looks like you want a template

Comment: Just curious why you would like to do this? There may be a better way to solve your problem.

Comment: It's possible, but why do you want to have a class with such a vague semantics?

Comment: Can you make the class a template, with ownership being controlled by the template parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines perhaps:

```
struct C {
  std::optional<T> t_holder;
  T& m_t;
  C(T& t) : m_t(t) {}
  C(T&& t) : t_holder(std::move(t)), m_t(*t_holder) {}
};
```

Would also need a copy and/or move constructor (the implicit one won't do the right thing); and the copy/move assignment operators would have to be deleted as I don't think they could be implemented reasonably. One way to salvage assignment would be to replace `T&` with `std::reference_wrapper<T>`; it behaves almost like a reference, but can be rebound.